# Caching full page in php but excluding a div tag

Tags: php, caching

**Using this code:**

```
<?php  
  // Define path and name of cached file    
  $cachefile = 'cache/'.date('M-d-Y').'.php';    

  // How long to keep cache file?   
  $cachetime = 18000;    

  // Is cache file still fresh? If so, serve it.     
  if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {    
     include($cachefile);        
     exit;    
  }   
  // if no file or too old, render and capture HTML page.
  ob_start();
?>


<html>        
Webpage content in here
</html>

<?php   
    // Save the cached content to a file    
    $fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');    
    fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());    
    fclose($fp);    

    // Send browser output    
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Is there a way to make a DIV tag on the page exempt from caching.. I have a page that can be completly cached except a price list which updates daily and wanted to stop that DIV from being cached

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean HTTP caching, then no, you can't do that.  In HTTP caching it's all or nothing.

If you mean server-side caching of a page that's expensive to generate, then you could cache the result of the first attempt to view the page to disc once every 24 hours with a cron job, and serve the generated page as a normal static page with the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the contents of your changing div into a PHP variable and send it to your cached file (basically using the cache file as a template with parameters).